# Can I use Clojure to build a mobile chat application?

Tags: android, mobile, clojure, chat, project

My project is to use build a simple chat client and I thinking of using Clojure since it is the language am currently learning. And am liking it.

I don't know whether this is possible and what the possibilities are.

I need advice or suggestions on what projects else I can do with Clojure as am just learning it now and would need some more experience to decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Clojurescript](http://clojure.org/clojurescript)? There are definitely possibilities here, though they can get quite involved. One possibility is to use something like [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) or [om](https://github.com/omcljs/om) to actually target the native platforms via javascript.

Probably a bit too advanced to start, but worth being aware of for a broader approach to targeting native platforms with clojure code.

Answer (score 4):

Plain Clojure is normally compiled to JVM bytecode but there's a project porting it to Android: http://clojure-android.info/.